# Como expor uma porta de um container nodejs criado com VSCODE Dev Container que possui um site estatico usando gulp?

Tags: visual-studio-code, docker, gulpjs

Eu tenho um projeto cujo repositorio se encontra [aqui](https://github.com/igoralves1/unify3.2.2).

Esse projeto é uma coleção de páginas estáticas em HTML com JavaScript e que usa Gulp.

Eu queria rodar esse projeto usando VsCode Dev Containers. O VsCode clona o repositório em questão e cria um container Node seguindo as espcificações.

O container está criado e rodando, com todos os arquivos carregados dentro dele mas nao consigo abrir o prjeto usando o Browser do Host.

Estou bloqueado em algum direcionamento da porta.

O objetivo final poder rodar o  site em um browser no host e o sistema todo armazenado no container.

Alguma ideia?